# Can I use Google Cloud Storage for Apache DocumentRoot?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I was reading [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/standard-storage) and saw the following:

> Standard Storage is appropriate for storing data that requires low latency access or data that is frequently accessed ("hot" objects), such as serving website content, interactive workloads, or data supporting mobile and gaming applications.

With that said, I wanted to know how would I go about mounting a gs://bucket? I would prefer to go this route than to create an NFS/GlusterFS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [gcsfuse](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse) to mount a Google Cloud Storage bucket as a filesystem that Apache can read:

> gcsfuse is a user-space file system for interacting with [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/).

As of 20 August 2015, the [project's README](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/README.md) also says:

> ## Current status
>
> Please treat gcsfuse as beta-quality software. Use it for whatever you like, but be aware that bugs may lurk, and that we reserve the right to make small backwards-incompatible changes.
>
> The careful user should be sure to read [semantics.md](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/semantics.md) for information on how gcsfuse maps file system operations to GCS operations, and especially on surprising behaviors. The list of [open issues](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse/issues) may also be of interest.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the information, @Misha. This def points me in the right direction